# Mdfind exclude a folder

Tags: macos, command-line, find, command

> -onlyin

option in mdfind searches a particular folder. 
How do I exclude certain folders in combination with -onlyin?

Thus if I want to search the entire folder SearchHere containing folders  A , B and C
and exclude from searching within C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
mdfind -onlyin SearchHere 'kMDItemFSName==ItemToSearch' | grep -v '/C/'
```

`mdfind` seems to ignore `kMDItemPath`, so using `grep -v` should solve the issue.